# Está correto o uso do $(selector).not(':visible') aqui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Eu estou refatorando o CSS de uma função do sistema e para tratar a propriedade do CSS e não uma string eu troquei **esta linha de código:** (da 1a maneira estava funcionando corretamente)

```
var ultimaMensagem = $("#box-confirm:not([style*='display: none;']),#box-erro:not([style*='display: none;'])").last();
```

**por esta:**

```
var ultimaMensagem = $('#box-confirm:not(:visible),#box-erro:not(:visible)').last();
```

**E assim o bloco de código ficou assim:**

```
GerenciadorModais.prototype.FecharModal = function () {        
        var ultimaModal = $(".modalJanela").last(); //Pegar a ultima Modal que será fechada

        //var ultimoBlock = $(".modal:not([style='display: none;'])").last(); //Maneira antiga
        var ultimoBlock = $(".modal:not(:visible)").last(); //Pegar a ultima div que será somente escondida

        //var ultimaMensagem = $("#box-confirm:not([style*='display: none;']),#box-erro:not([style*='display: none;'])").last(); //Maneira antiga
        var ultimaMensagem = $('#box-confirm:not(:visible),#box-erro:not(:visible)').last(); //Pegar a ultima div de mensagem que será somente escondida

        if (ultimoBlock.length > 0) { // Deixar invisivel essa div
            ultimoBlock.css('display', 'none'); 
        } else 
            if (ultimaMensagem.length > 0) { // Deixar invisivel essa div
                ultimaMensagem.css('display', 'none'); 
            } else { // fechar essa modal
                ultimaModal.remove(); 
                $(".block").last().remove();
                this.nivelModal--;
            }

        if (!$(".modalJanela").length > 0) //Fechar a layer escura
            $('#btn-center-dialog').fadeOut();
    };
```

[image: debugger do JS]

[URL DA IMAGEM ACIMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0wTT.png)

Eu levei em consideração o que está escrito neste post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425543/difference-between-hidden-and-notvisible-in-jquery

Mas eu não tenho certeza se isso não trará problemas futuros. Basicamente eu preciso pegar todos os #box-confirm e #box-erro que estão invisíveis de alguma maneira na tela.

**Então minhas dúvidas são:**

**1)** Por que não funciona essa alteração?
Obs.: Estou fazendo uns testes e reparei que o que não está funcionando é o ultimo `else` que realmente fecha uma modal, mas isso provavelmente está acontecendo por que ele está tentando fechar uma das divs e não a modal.

**2)** Existe alguma possibilidade de que ele não pegue o ultimo seletor que esteja invisível na tela?

**3)** Existe alguma maneira melhor de fazer isso ou essa já é a melhor solução?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso o correto não seria `#box-confirm:not(:visible)`, mas sim `#box-confirm:visible` pois `:not()` com `style*='display: none;'` procura elementos visíveis como dito pelo @falsarella.

### :visible vs seletor por atributos

Supondo que usando o original o e seu html fosse:

```
<div style="display:none !important;">
```

Em alguns navegadores (se não em todos) o seletor não o encontraria.

Realmente o melhor é usar o `:visible` pois ele verifica tanto:

1. `DOM.style.display !== "none"`
2. `DOM.style.visibility === "visible"`
3. `<input type="hidden">`

### Seletor por classe e performance

Outro que você pode usar (que pode ser em micro-optimização mais rápido) seria uma classe:

```
.hide { display:none; }
```

Desta maneira:

```
var ultimaMensagem = $('#box-confirm.hide,#box-erro.hide').last();
```

Ele é mais rápido teoricamente devido a fazer apenas uma verificação, enquanto no `:visible`, ele pode fazer mais de uma (dependendo da situação).

Note também que `:visible` é um seletor jQuery e não padrão, portanto neste caso o jquery não vai usar o `querySelector` (que é mais rápido por ser nativo). Já os seletores por classe são nativos.

**Nota:** o jQuery usa o `querySelector` (ou `querySelectorAll`) quando há suporte para a função e para o seletor, tornando as consultas mais rápidas.

Comment: @MaiconCarraro quando notar um erro de digitação pode editar :)

Comment: Farei das próximas vezes :)

Comment: Obrigado! Eu apoio as edições!! kk - obrigado por me atentar ao problema, já corrigi.

Comment: Guilherme, eu fiz a alteração, mas eu não sei porque não está funcionando... :/

Comment: Eu editei o post com mais informação para ser possível responder uma das partes da pergunta.

Comment: Poderia mostrar uma parte do html? @AndreyHartung

Comment: Qual parte? Que tu precisa que eu mostre?

Comment: Estou fazendo uns testes e reparei que o que não está funcionando é o ultimo `else` que realmente fecha uma modal

Comment: @AndreyHartung o elemento com `class="modalJanela"` e `#box-confirm` além de também precisar do css. Leia por favor: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Eu to ligado no mcve, mas é que estou refatorando o fecharModal de um sistema MVC gigante que usa razor e deus sabe la o que mais

Comment: Guilherme eu editei o post com o debugger do JS, creio que com isso ja deve ajudar

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Está quase. Falta apenas rever os textos: *Não está errada está alteração*, por exemplo.

Comment: @falsarella []s feito

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade, `:not([style*='display: none;'])` deveria ser traduzido para `:visible`, e não para `:not(:visible)`.

Afinal, um elemento que ***não*** tem `display: none;` é visível.

Comment: Eu alterei, mas está dando erro. Estou escrevendo isso certo? `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .modal(:visible)` ou `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .modal:(:visible)`

Comment: Acho que assim fica mais facil de entender: `var ultimoBlock = $(".modal(:visible)").last();` Isso aqui está está errado, saberia dizer qual a maneira correta?

Comment: Tente `.modal:visible`.

Comment: \Õ/ deste jeito que tu postou funcionou na modal \o/ Obrigado! Agora só falta eu verificar se está ok nos outros 2 casos

Comment: Funcionou em todos os casos! Obrigado!

Comment: Tem razão, falta de atenção minha +1

Comment: @AndreyHartung Que bom! Espero que tenha entendido o porquê! Bons estudos! =)